# Computing cosine similarity using Python

Tags: text, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have written the following code to compute the cosine similarity between a number of preprocessed document (stop word removal, stemming and term frequency-inverse document frequency).

```
print(X.shape)
similarity = []
for each in X:
    similarity.append(cosine_similarity(X[i:1], X))
    print(cosine_similarity(X[i:1], X))
    i = i+1
```

However, when I run it I receive this:

```
(2235, 7791)
[[ 1.          0.01490594  0.11752643 ...,  0.00941571  0.03652551
   0.01239277]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 83, in <module>
    similarity.append(cosine_similarity(X[i:1], X))
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 881, in cosine_similarity
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 96, in check_pairwise_arrays
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=dtype)
  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 407, in check_array
    context))
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 7791)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
[Finished in 56.466s]
```

Comment: You are using X[i:1] inside your loop. When i reaches 1, you are accessing X[1:1] which returns an empty list. That's causing the error.

Comment: @DileepKumarPatchigolla How can I do it then?

Comment: I am not familiar with the cosine_similarity. Can you provide the sample of how X looks like, so I can try it out?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  In the code you posted, **cosine_similarity**, **i**, and **X** are undefined, so it's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: You could try like this to get the cosine similarity between the first vector and the rest: `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(X[0:1], X, metric='cosine', n_jobs=1)` . http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html  (http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/ )

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  You're taking a cosine similarity between a slice of the matrix **X** and the entire matrix.  The slice is empty except when i == 0.  Your **for** statement iterates through the matrix, but you never use the iteration variable **each**.

Cosine similarity is an operation between two vectors of equal length.  For instance, you can compute the similarity between row **i** and row **j** with

```
cosine_similarity(X[i], X[j])
```

If you want all of the row-to-row similarities computed in a list, use a list comprehension:

```
similarity = [cosine_similarity(a, b) for a in X for b in X]
```

Does that get you moving?